# How to increase number of breaks on x axis in echarts4r plot?

Tags: javascript, r, echarts, echarts4r

I am making a simple histogram in echarts4r, but I am struggling to override the default x axis labels. For example in the plot below, I would like to have a label at every 3rd, instead of intervals of 5.

```
library(echarts4r)
  mtcars |>
    e_charts() |>
    e_histogram(mpg, name = "histogram",  breaks =seq(0,36,3))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the interval between ticks as well as the min and max values using `e_x_axis` like so:

See also [the docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.interval) for more options.

```
library(echarts4r)
mtcars |>
  e_charts() |>
  e_histogram(mpg, name = "histogram",  breaks = seq(0,36,3)) |>
  e_x_axis(interval = 3, min = 3, max = 36)
```

[image]